# Lable update on checkbox selected

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have a gridview within TabContainer control that has a checkbox item.  I am firing the javascript to display an alert with the number of checkboxes selected.

I now want to update the label text on the screen with the count of selected checkboxes rather than showing the alert but I do not know how to reference the label.

See code below.  Ideas or pointing me to a similar post would be appreciated.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="MasterContent" runat="server">

<script type="text/javascript">

    function CheckBoxCount() {
        var gv = document.getElementById("<%= gv02ROLE.ClientID %>");
        var inputList = gv.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var numChecked = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
            if (inputList[i].type == "checkbox" && inputList[i].checked) {
                numChecked = numChecked + 1;
            }
        }
        alert(numChecked);            
        <<< set text value for ID="statusLabel1" to replace this alert >>>
    }
</script>         

<asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="0" AutoPostBack="true">
.
<asp:TabPanel ID="TabREVROLE" runat="server" HeaderText="Open Review" Visible="false">
<ContentTemplate>
    .
    <asp:Label ID="statusLabel1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>


    <asp:GridView ID="gv02ROLE" runat="server" AllowPaging="True"  
                      ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" AllowSorting="True" ShowHeader="true"
        .
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select" Visible="true" HeaderStyle-Width="10" 
                      ItemStyle-Width="10">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="selCheck" runat="server" CssClass="mychk" 
                                   Checked="false" Enabled="true" 
                                    onClick="javascript:CheckBoxCount()"/>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I briefly saw an initial answer on this to use this code:

```
`document.getElementById('<%=statusLabel1.ClientID%>').innerHTML = numChecked`
```

This solution worked. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("statusLabel1").value = numChecked
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply:

```
function CheckBoxCount() {
    var gv = document.getElementById("<%= gv02ROLE.ClientID %>"),
        inputList = gv.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked'),
        textProp = 'textContent' in document ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';

    document.getElementById('statusLabel1')[textProp] = inputList.length;
}
```

References:

- [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.getElementById).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll).
- [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent).

Comment: I tried this and received Error: Unable to set property 'textContent' of undefined or null reference.

Comment: I saw an early post that recommended:  document.getElementById('<%=statusLabel1.ClientID%>').innerHTML = numChecked and this worked.